# CLIアプリケーションをjavascriptで実装する際に、デバッグはどのように行ったらいいでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

CLI内で完結するアプリケーションをjavascriptで作成しているプロジェクトがあり、
そのプロジェクトに来週から参画する予定です。

そのキャッチアップのために現在、ソースコードを読んでおります。

いくつか気になった点があるため、ローカル環境でデバッグをしたかったのですが、
ブレークポイントなどを設定し、そこでの変数などを確かめる方法がわかりませんでした。

web上であれば、ブラウザのデバッグツールを用いて、ブレークポイントを設定したりできますが、
今回のようにCLIで完結するアプリケーションのため、IDEなどを使うのかなと思い、以下のようなサイトを漁っておりました。

http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2137182325409098101

IDE自体は色々とあるみたいですが、今回の要件にあったIDEもしくはデバッグツールがどれなのかがわからず困っております。

単体ファイルのみを検証したい場合は、最悪、ブラウザのデバッグツールを用いようかと思ったのですが、
今回のプロジェクトでは、ファイルも複数ファイルにまたがりそれらをrequireしたりしているため、できれば他の方法で対応したいと考えております。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

iron-nodeを使ってみてはいかかでしょう。

https://github.com/s-a/iron-node

nodeで実行するかわりに、iron-nodeと実行するだけでChrome Developer Toolsが立ち上がりブラウザと同じようにデバックすることができます。
導入は`npm i -g iron-node`でnpmからインストールできます。

Answer (score 0):

私が hubot のデバッグがしたい時には、下記のサイトを参考に、 chrome の devtool をデバッガとして使用しました。

[node-inspector で hubot をデバッグする - Qiita](http://qiita.com/hori@github/items/5a566237a66237e70d37)

もっともシンプルなものは、下記かと思います。

[はじめてのNode.js：Node.jsアプリケーションのデバッグ | OSDN Magazine](https://osdn.jp/magazine/13/04/16/080000)